# How to redirect to Home page from another page without loosing input data by user at Home page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am giving inputs in `home.aspx` page and redirecting to other page say `Viewpage.aspx` and putted Home redirection on `Viewpage.aspx` Like `switching tabs`.

I don't want to load Home page again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple option to retain the data on redirection , Mostly used check the postback while loading, So you can achieve it by localstorage option using javascript,

```
<script>
// Run on page load
window.onload = function() {

    // If sessionStorage is storing default values (ex. name), exit the function and do not restore data
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('name') == "name") {
        return;
    }

    // If values are not blank, restore them to the fields
    var name = sessionStorage.getItem('name');
    if (name !== null) $('#inputName').val(name);

    var email = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
    if (email !== null) $('#inputEmail').val(email);

    var subject= sessionStorage.getItem('subject');
    if (subject!== null) $('#inputSubject').val(subject);

    var message= sessionStorage.getItem('message');
    if (message!== null) $('#inputMessage').val(message);
}

// Before refreshing the page, save the form data to sessionStorage
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("name", $('#inputName').val());
    sessionStorage.setItem("email", $('#inputEmail').val());
    sessionStorage.setItem("subject", $('#inputSubject').val());
    sessionStorage.setItem("message", $('#inputMessage').val());
}
```